# New column in my table not visible after adding and publishing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I have an existing table => zoo[design] I add to it new column:

```
zooName nvarchar(50) allow null
```

Then I updated the server but when i go in zoo[data] and push refresh I can't see the zooName there.

But if I make new Query

```
select * from zoo
```

it's display for me the zooName but i can't edit it in the zoo[data]

I closed the project and open it again then it's ok

I don't want to open and close the project every time I need to add new row.

Comment: are you editing your database project in visual studio?

Comment: What is the language you are developing in? Is this EF?

Comment: _Then I updated the server but when i go in zoo[data] and push refresh I can't see the zooName there_ what does this mean? What tool are you _pushing refresh_ in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refresh on your database node from Object Explorer if you are using MSSQL.